# regular expression and substitution

Tags: regex, latex, replace

In Latex, I had a lot of math expressions with subscriptions in terms of `123`, now, I need to change them to `\alpha \beta \gamma` instead of `123`.
 for example:

`$E_{223}$` to `$E_{\beta\beta\gamma}$`

and

`$E_{31}$` to `$_{\gamma\alpha}$`

However, I also have power index which is not supposed to be altered, such as `$E^3_{112}$` should be change to `$E^3_{\alpha\alpha\beta}$.`

Is there a way to use regular expression to make this task easier? I know some regular expression from unix and perl, but seems inadequate for this problem.

thank you for anything!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% familiar with Latex, but typical regex would look like this:

```
(?<\^)#
```

Where the `#` is 1, 2 or 3. Then, in your replace, you would replace the matches with `\alpha`, `\beta` and `\gamma`. The `(?<\^)` is a negative look-behind that says to only replace instances of that number when they aren't preceded by a `^` character (your power indicator).

If typical regex doesn't permit, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: One possible issue: This won't work if the exponent is more than one digit (ex. `$E^12_{345}$`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what editor or regex engine you're using for this, but here's the basic idea I'd go with in Perl-ish regex:

Replace this:

```
(?<=\{\d*)1(?=\d*\})
```

With this:

```
\\alpha
```

I think you'll want to set the `g` flag as well.

Not sure if I have the right escaping syntax (it's been a while since I touched Perl) but I think so.

Repeat as necessary for \beta, \gamma, etc.

Comment: Syntax error marked HERE: `(?<\<---HERE`, also you are trying to use a variable length lookbehind, that doesn't work well in Perlish regex.

Comment: @Qtax - Typo, I meant `(?<=`, not `(?<`...but if variable-length lookbehinds aren't allowed, I'll have to defer to someone who knows Perl better than I do. I'll delete this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- replace `(?<!\^\d|\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{4})1` with `\alpha`
- replace `(?<!\^\d|\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{4})2` with `\beta`
- replace `(?<!\^\d|\d{2}|\d{3}|\d{4})3` with `\gamma`

Edit:  These regexes make sure that it won't replace a number from an exponent.  You may have to tweak them to check for optional `-` if you have negative exponents.

Edit 2: @QTax pointed out that you can't use a variable length lookbehinds.

> Subexp of look-behind must be fixed character length.
>                        But different character length is allowed in top level
>                        alternatives only.

Reference: http://tacosw.com/latexian/help/find/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you could do things like:

```
$text =~ s@\$\w[^${\s]*_{\K([123]+)(?=}\$)@
    local $_ = $1;
    s/1/\\alpha/g; s/2/\\beta/g; s/3/\\gamma/g;
    $_
@ge;
```